# Javascript to allow character ` &#x60; inside multiline strings

Tags: javascript, string, multiline, ace-editor

Basicly, I want to initialize my editor (ace editor) with initial script from the backend. But, for some case, the `initialScript` also includes the (`), ('), (") characters. So, I confuse how to use that `initialScript` without changing them.

> Because: when I parse that `initialScript` into html decode *(html entities, like: `&#x60;`)*, in editor also show `&#x60;`.

```
var initialScript = `from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


def generate_unique_slug(klass, field):
    """
    return unique slug if origin slug is exist.
    eg: `foo-bar` => `foo-bar-1`
    :param `klass` is Class model.
    :param `field` is specific field for title.
    """
    origin_slug = slugify(field)
    unique_slug = origin_slug
    numb = 1
    while klass.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '%s-%d' % (origin_slug, numb)
        numb += 1
    return unique_slug


brian='Hello life!'`;
```

Also in my editor config;

```
var initialScript = `{{ session_initial_script|default:'' }}`;
var editor = ace.edit('editor');
    editor.setTheme('ace/theme/twilight');
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/python');
    editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
    editor.getSession().setValue(initialScript);
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: use backslash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backslash in front of special characters

```
var initialScript = `from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


def generate_unique_slug(klass, field):
    """
    return unique slug if origin slug is exist.
    eg: \`foo-bar\` => \`foo-bar-1\`
    :param \`klass\` is Class model.
    :param \`field\` is specific field for title.
    """
    origin_slug = slugify(field)
    unique_slug = origin_slug
    numb = 1
    while klass.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '%s-%d' % (origin_slug, numb)
        numb += 1
    return unique_slug


brian='Hello life!'`
```

Comment: No problem see you around